# stop images from fitting to screen on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a page of images that are all different widths example:

```
<img src="#" width="650px">
<img src="#" width="750px">
<img src="#" width="350px">
```

On the resize of the browser, these will break out of the container, so I have to set `max-width: 100%;` on the img to stop this from happening.

Is there a way that I can get these images to retain their different size aspects?
At the moment they all end up at being the full width of the mobile browser.

Comment: Show us what you have ended up with... This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the `max-width` is fine , just try ot also add a `height:auto;`

Example: ( resize the window to see effect )

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg">
<img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg">
<img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg">
```

Comment: I can see this works perfectly fine in your example but when I test it, it doesn't work. Weird, thanks for the answer tho I'm glad I wasn't going about it the wrong way, I'll try to figure out what is causing it to not do this.

Comment: Check in inspect element if the code is set on the `img` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: auto;` to the image css

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a9ff3b_1eec973ae9eb43f4bca9876e5d90f6fa.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some more css here, if I am right currently on mobile portrait mode you are getting all images having full width but on landscape all should have different sizes.

In portrait mode average screen width is approx.320px but you have all images more then 320px.

So I suggest you yo use classes like ".large" ".medium" and ".small" for images and use media query for mobile/small screens to show different width.